# Excel transform data

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have data that looks as in below table

| Name | Subject 1 | Mark 1 | Subject 2 | Mark 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test | Biology | 90 | Physics | 80 |

**and would like to convert the above data as below.**

| Name | Subject | Mark |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test | Biology | 90 |
| Test | Physics | 80 |

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to create an extra column, where you copy the "Name" field:

| Name | Subject 1 | Mark 1 | Name | Subject 2 | Mark 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test | Biology | 90 | =A2 | Physics | 80 |

... and then copy the right half under the existing table (paste as values).

Comment: This is quite manual , is there a way to make it automatically done?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called "[Unpivot columns](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098)" in Excel Power query.

You need to load this table in Power query and select all the "SubjectN" columns and click Unpivot. Refer to the [following video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQS5V6_AGn8) for example